# MUI styled component, accessing inner css classes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to access the inner CSS of a MUI `Alert` by passing styles to the `icon` CSS rule of the Alert component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { spacing } from "@material-ui/system";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    icon: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  }),
);

const MyAlert = styled(Alert)(spacing);

export default function SimpleAlerts() {
  const styles = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <MyAlert classes={{icon: styles.icon}}>This is an error alert — check it out!</MyAlert>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but even though the styling works fine, the console keeps complaining

`` Material-UI: The key `icon` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Alert)). ``

How can I avoid this (console) error?

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-prvzq?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you need to do is replace

`classes={{icon: styles.icon}}`
with
`className={styles.icon}`

Did that help?

Comment: Thanks, that removed the error, but the styling as well ...